# Django Oracle Connection

Tags: django, database, oracle, ora-12170

I'm using Oracle 11g and Django 1.5.1.
I have installed cx_Oracle, import cx_Oracle works fine.
I setup database settings like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default' : {
        'ENGINE' : 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME' : 'XE',
        'USER' : 'system',
        'PASSWORD' : 'mypass',
        'HOST' : '127.0.0.1'
        'PORT' : '1521'
    }
}
```

When I said

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

it said

```
DatabaseError: ORA-12170: TNS:Connection timeout occurred.
```

I can connect to database with Navicat.

Answer (score 0):

This error means it was unsuccessful in making a tcp connection to 127.0.0.1 port 1521

As root, or the user running the Oracle database, what address is shown for the LISTENing port in the output of    lsof -Pni:1521

If it is not 127.0.0.1:1521 or *:1521, then it won't be listening on 127.0.0.1

However. This is a connection timeout, not something like port unreachable (connection refused)

You didn't say if you were running navicat from the same machine or a different machine. If the above command shows only 127.0.0.1:1521, then it's only listening on that IP address, and would need to be changed to allow connections from other machines, if that is what you are trying to achieve.

Check for firewall rules that may block traffic.

If attempting to connect remotely, doing a network trace can be useful to determine the problem. I recently had an issue similar to this that caused ARP to malfunction. You can see how I diagnosed that particular issue at http://distracted-it.blogspot.co.nz/2014/04/ora-12170-tnsconnect-timeout-resolved.html